# Best case for seeding large data in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have a file with over 30,000 records and another with 41,000. Is there a best case study for seeding this using laravel 4's `db:seed` command? A way to make the inserts more swift.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you looking for Benchmarks or a way to enter in the queries quickly? Do you run into issues (memory timeouts?) with the seed or is it just slow?

Comment: Which driver are you using?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't be afraid, 40K rows table is kind of a small one. I have a 1 milion rows table and seed was done smoothly, I just had to add this before doing it:

```
DB::disableQueryLog();
```

Before disabling it, Laravel wasted all my PHP memory limit, no matter how much I gave it.

I read data from .txt files using `fgets()`, building the array programatically and executing:

```
DB::table($table)->insert($row);
```

One by one, wich may be particularily slow.

My database server is a PostgreSQL and inserts took around 1.5 hours to complete, maybe because I was using a VM using low memory. I will make a benchmark one of these days on a better machine.

Comment: Antonio, how is your application working in regards to performance with the large database?

Comment: Those records are all zipcodes from my contry, users type the zip code and the app get and show a full address. As far as I can tell it's really fast. My database is PostgreSQL.

Comment: 1.5m records(iterations) took ~650s.
Used cmd - RequestProcessResult::insert($rr);

Comment: If someone is still having issues here, Just created over 42k entries in less than 30s ..checkout my answer below for details how i did it.

Answer (score 9):

#### 2018 Update

I have run into the same issue and after 2 days of headache, I could finally write script to seed 42K entries in less than 30s!

You ask How?

#### 1st Method

This method assumes that you have a database with some entries in it(in my case were 42k entries) and you want to import same into other database. Export your database as CSV files with header names and put the file into the public folder of your project and then you can parse the file and insert one by one all the entries in new database via seeder.

So your seeder will look something like this:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class {TableName}TableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $row = 1;
        if (($handle = fopen(base_path("public/name_of_your_csv_import.csv"), "r")) !== false) {
            while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",")) !== false) {
                if ($row === 1) {
                    $row++;
                    continue;
                }
                $row++;

                $dbData = [
                    'col1' => '"'.$data[0].'"',
                    'col2' => '"'.$data[1].'"',
                    'col3' => '"'.$data[2].'"',
                    so on...how many columns you have
                ];

                $colNames = array_keys($dbData);

                $createQuery = 'INSERT INTO locations ('.implode(',', $colNames).') VALUES ('.implode(',', $dbData).')';

                DB::statement($createQuery, $data);
                $this->command->info($row);
            }
            fclose($handle);
        }
    }
}
```

Simple and Easy :)

---

#### 2nd method

In case you can modify the settings of your PHP and allocate a big size to aprticular script then this method will work as well.

Well basically you need to focus on three major steps:

- Allocate more memory to script
- Off Query Logger
- Divide your data in chunks of 1000
- Iterate through data and use `insert()` to create chunks of 1K at a time.

So if I combine all of the above mentioned steps in a seeder, your seeder will look something like this:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class {TableName}TableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');//allocate memory
        DB::disableQueryLog();//disable log
        //create chunks
        $data = [
           [
              [
                 'col1'=>1,
                 'col2'=>1,
                 'col3'=>1,
                 'col4'=>1,
                 'col5'=>1
              ],
              [             
                 'col1'=>1,
                 'col2'=>1,
                 'col3'=>1,
                 'col4'=>1,
                 'col5'=>1
              ],
              so on..until 1000 entries 
           ],
           [
              [
                 'col1'=>1,
                 'col2'=>1,
                 'col3'=>1,
                 'col4'=>1,
                 'col5'=>1
              ],
              [             
                 'col1'=>1,
                 'col2'=>1,
                 'col3'=>1,
                 'col4'=>1,
                 'col5'=>1
              ],
              so on..until 1000 entries 
           ],
           so on...until how many entries you have, i had 42000
      ]
      //iterate and insert
      foreach ($data as $key => $d) {
          DB::table('locations')->insert($d);
          $this->command->info($key);//gives you an idea where your iterator is in command line, best feeling in the world to see it rising if you ask me :D
      }
  }
}
```

and VOILA you are good to go :)

*I hope it helps*

Answer (score 0):

I was migrating from a different database and I had to use raw sql (loaded from an external file) with bulk insert statements (I exported structure via navicat which has the option to break up your insert statements every 250KiB). Eg:

```
$sqlStatements = array(
"INSERT INTO `users` (`name`, `email`)
VALUES
    ('John Doe','john.doe@gmail.com'),.....
    ('Jane Doe','jane.doe@gmail.com')",
"INSERT INTO `users` (`name`, `email`)
VALUES
    ('John Doe2','john.doe2@gmail.com'),.....
    ('Jane Doe2','jane.doe2@gmail.com')"
);
```

I then looped through the insert statements and executed using

```
DB::statement($sql).
```

I couldn't get insert to work one row at a time. I'm sure there's alternatives that are better but this at least worked while letting me keep it within Laravel's migration/seeding.

Comment: correction, apparently it was probably the same DB, didn't notice it was you Ralph :-) StackOverflow isn't so big apparently

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today.  Disabling query log wasn't enough. Looks like an event also get fired.

> DB::disableQueryLog();
>
> // DO INSERTS
>
> // Reset events to free up memory.
>
> DB::setEventDispatcher(new Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher());